# SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert lat and long coordinates into a SQLite table and I am getting `SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed`.

I have the code surrounded by try/catch and no exception is thrown. I get the constraint error in my logcat.

I have attached the DB class and the call from my main activity. Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated!

Here are the top few lines from my logcat:

```
08-25 14:39:06.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(681): Error inserting lat=59310767 longi=-8613281
08-25 14:39:06.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(681): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
08-25 14:39:06.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(681):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
08-25 14:39:06.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(681):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
08-25 14:39:06.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(681):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1745)
08-25 14:39:06.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(681):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1618)
```

Here is the code from my DbHelper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            KEY_LAT + " REAL NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_LONGI + " REAL NOT NULL)" 

            // KEY_NAME + " TEXT NULL, " +
            // KEY_INFO + " TEXT NULL);"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Here is my DatabaseManager

```
public DatabaseManager(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public DatabaseManager open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDB = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //example show writeable
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
} 

public long createPin(long latitude, long longitude) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_LAT, latitude);
    cv.put(KEY_LONGI, longitude);

    return ourDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

This is the call from my MainActivity:

```
try{
    long longitude= touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6();
    long latitude= touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6();

    //Add Pin to the Database
    DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(MainActivity.this);
    db.open();
    db.createPin(latitude,longitude);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other tables or triggers?

Comment: What happens if you convert your `long` values to `float` before inserting? For example in your `createPin(...)` method, try `cv.put(KEY_LAT, latitude.floatValue());` and the same for longitude.

Comment: good point Squonk. The similar java datatype of real is double.

Comment: Ah, I did also think about suggesting `doubleValue()` but I've never used REAL as a column type so wasn't sure of the equivalence.

Comment: "Sam: No I don't have any triggers." But do you have any other tables (especially with foreign keys)? Also, use the "add comment" feature here in your question and you can notify an individual user with "@Sam". I only found your comment by chance.

Comment: Hi Squonk, I tried changing the vales to float and double but the error is still the same. Can you think of anything else I could try?

Answer (score 2):

remove the keyword AUTOINCREMENT.
It is not necessaty for sqlite.
if you try to insert a null value into a primary integer key the field is automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the largest value of that column.

Furthermore you have to clear your appdata on your emulator. After that you can be sure that the database is empty.

Comment: True that it is implied with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. But how does this fail any contraints?

Comment: Yes thats an open issue. but the primary key is the only possible point for that exception or longtitude or latitude is null...

Comment: Thanks BC_ I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi BC_, I removed AUTOINCREMENT but still get the same error. I have tried removing the id and all sorts. Can you think of anything I should try. I have also changed the lat and long's to float and double and this too has not worked.

Comment: you changed the fields to float and double???
Please try following: ourDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
add this line before the insert.(it's just for testing :) )

Comment: Was reading an old logcat message. You suggestion probably worked. Thank you very much for your help with this, it really has helped me!

Comment: BC_ just tested it and it was your solution that worked. I doff my cap to you. Have a very nice evening!

Comment: Realy? Very good :-) Then click on the hook left of my answer. you get help faster if you accept the correct answers in this forum.

Comment: @StefanBeike hi, Probably I am getting same issue. so as per your suggestion I should delete everything from DB before inserting anything?

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**: `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of `AUTOINCREMENT`
                  ^

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT add Underscore

Comment: Why? `AUTOINCREMENT` works fine. `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not listed among [SQLite's keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Where is an example or documentation supporting `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Sam: No I don't have any triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your time!! No i dont use triggers. Squonk, I will try your suggestion.